# bazel-bin/dragnn/tools/build_pip_package: No such file or directory

Tags: syntaxnet

I'm trying to install SyntaxNet on Mac OS X (Sierra 10.12.4), and I've gotten to the step beginning:

`Now you can install the SyntaxNet and DRAGNN Python modules with the following commands:`

And I've tried the next command: 

`bazel-bin/dragnn/tools/build_pip_package --output-dir=/tmp/syntaxnet_pkg`

And I get the message:

`-bash: bazel-bin/dragnn/tools/build_pip_package: No such file or directory`

And indeed, when I go look in the folder (alias) bazel-bin, there is no dragnn subfolder, which I guess there is supposed to be given the previous steps? But I think I've followed them (the bazel test passes), and still no such folder.

Comment: clone all the latest files with git tools , like "Tower 2.6.1". The commond "git clone" can not clone all the files .

Comment: Hmm, how am I supposed to know the full list of files I need to clone?

Comment: @DavidSchueler Did you manage to solve this problem?

Comment: Yes I did; don't remember how though. I just tried a bunch of things I think.